# WordPress отключиться от интернета?

Tags: wordpress

Warning: Произошла непредвиденная ошибка. Возможно, что-то не так с сайтом WordPress.org или с настройками вашего сервера. Если проблема не решится, обратитесь на форумы поддержки. (Не удалось установить защищённое соединение с WordPress.org. Пожалуйста, свяжитесь с администратором сервера.) in Z:\home\word.ru\www\wordpress\wp-includes\update.php on line 295

Сайт создаю локальный, а затем будет внутренним, то есть привязка к интернету не нужна. Каким образом отключить сайт от интернета?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле **wp-config.php** можно  объявить константы, которые выключат все связи Wordpress с обновлениями, но это также отключит обновления тем и плагинов, насколько мне известно.

Объявите следующие константы в wp-config.php:

```
define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true);
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

Comment: уже поменял
 
     define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
// Отключить автоматическое обновление ядра
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
/* Это всё, дальше не редактируем. Успехов! */

а ошибка осталась 

Warning: Произошла непредвиденная ошибка. Возможно, что-то не так с сайтом WordPress.org или с настройками вашего сервера. Если проблема не решится, обратитесь на форумы поддержки. (Не удалось установить защищённое соединение с WordPress.org. Пожалуйста, свяжитесь с администратором сервера.) in Z:\home\word.lc\www\wordpress\wp-includes\update.php on line 457

Comment: @anunak, а с интернетом все работает? Помнится, устанавливал 1 млн раз wordpress на локалку и не видел ничего подобного, и без интернета тоже.

Comment: @anunak, я только сейчас заметил, что это "Warning", по идее, не должно влиять на работоспособность или не работает wordpress вообще?